# How do I add a radius to a tp command with another specification?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a certain amount of villagers look a certain way, but I can't figure out how to add a radius (so only some of the villagers look that way).

My command is `/tp @e[type=Villager] ~ ~ ~ -90 30`

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
/tp @e[type=Villager,r=N] ~ ~ ~ -90 30
```

"N" is the size (in blocks) of the radius.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/tp @e[type=villager,distance=..N] ...`